# count frequencies of occurrences of items in a dictionary and update it in dictionary itself

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

i've a dict d as below:

```
d
{'EventThread': [40002], 'kworker/u16:13': [80002], 'kworker/u16:0': [80002], 'AudioOut_D': [80002, 80002, 80002, 80002, 80002, 80002], 'putmethod.latin': [80002], 'surfaceflinger': [40002], 'InputDispatcher': [80002]}
```

I want something similar to:

```
d
{'AudioOut_D': [80002:6 ,40002:1]}
```

which indicates frequencies of items

I tried code below:

```
print((collections.Counter(d['AudioOut_D'])))
Counter({80002: 6})
```

but then how to update this into dictionay

TIA code for how to generate dict is as follows:

```
self._sched_task_load_flags = defaultdict(list)
def sched_task_load_handler(self,thread):
        "accepts threads and builds corresponding threads and flags co-relation"
        _sched_task_load_flags = self._sched_task_load_flags
        try:
            while True:
                record = (yield)
                if "sched_task_load"==record["function"]:
                    flags = record["flags"]
                else:
                    print "error in sched_task_load_function_parse"
                    raise Exception
```

How to combine two operations in loop  below:

```
e = {k: dict(Counter(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

this works great, but I also need to get a list of all flags as below:

```
for k,v in flags.iteritems():
    list_of_all_flags.append(list(Counter(v)))
```

how is it possible to combine above two loops in one TIA

Comment: First of all `{'AudioOut_D': [80002:6 ,40002:1]}` is not a Valid Python Syntax, **`[80002:6 ,40002:1]`** makes no sense

Comment: I meant to say i need counts/frequency of events along with its type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you may apply `Counter()` method on each value as:

```
from collections import Counter
e = {k: dict(Counter(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

Output:

```
    {'AudioOut_D': {80002: 6},
 'EventThread': {40002: 1},
 'InputDispatcher': {80002: 1},
 'kworker/u16:0': {80002: 1},
 'kworker/u16:13': {80002: 1},
 'putmethod.latin': {80002: 1},
 'surfaceflinger': {40002: 1}}
```

Comment: I want to combine two operations with above loop as follows: